# How to rename files according to other files?

Tags: linux

I have several files in a folder with extension `.img`  and I have only one file with extension `data.txt`
What I need is to copy `data.txt` and rename it as the names of the .img files.

For instance  for the first file in my folder:

```
`Meaurmen_2154_data.img`  >>> copy data.txt >>> rename it Meaurmen_2154_data.txt  
 Now I have :
Meaurmen_2154_data.img  
Meaurmen_2154_data.txt  ## the content is the same as data.txt
```

and do the same for all other files. The content of he text files will be the same for all files just we change the name according to the .img files in my folder.

Comment: And you want to do it in Fortran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this script

```
#!/bin/bash

imageFiles=( *.img );
for i in ${imageFiles[*]}
do
    withoutExtension=${i%.img};
    cp data.txt "$withoutExtension.txt";
done
```

inside the relevant directory and it will do it for you.

Comment: @bicton That's an artifact from copying and pasting the script from the internet. That means that a carriage return ('\r') was copied from StackOverflow's markdown/HTML into your file, which can really mess up a script. \r resets streams to the beginning of a line so it causes real chaos. It also explains why the error say "yscript" instead of "myscript". You should copy the script by hand or write a program to get rid of any carriage returns in the file.

Comment: @bicton that's very strange. There shouldn't be any '\r' in there at all. What text editor are you using?

Comment: @bicton make sure you copy what up there now. I changed it from when I first posted.

Comment: @bicton no I mean are you using nano or vim or what?

Comment: @bicton  That makes sense then. In windows the newline character is \r\n but in UNIX/Linux \r is a carriage return and \n is newline. You need your file to only have \n without any \r. You should go on your Linux machine and type what I wrote using nano.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for i in *.img; do cp data.txt $i.txt; done
rename 's/.img.txt/.txt/' *.img.txt
```

In some distro's rename is different, requiring

```
rename .img.txt .txt *.img.txt
```

As always, you might find yourself in need of installing additional packages.